# need resize-able datatype for xy coordinate system

Tags: c#, dynamic-data, coordinate-systems

I am coding a program to modify select chunks of a simple 3d game map ([minecraft](http://www.ruebenreleeshahn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/MineCraftCastle.jpg)).  The map can be [theoretically very large](http://www.overclock.net/pc-games/673291-minecraft-indev.html#post8564015) so loading the entire map is out of the question.  I want to only load each 16x16 sized chunk once and have those chunks in memory should I need to modify it again.  I need a data structure to store these portions in memory in an (x,y) coordinate fashion while being able to resize this data structure as needed and keep it orderly so I can find specific chunks.
I am at a loss on what data structure I could use to meet my requirements.  I am hoping someone could make some suggestions.  I am coding in c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend a top level `Map` data structure that has an indexer based on a `Coordinate`. Next add a `Chunk` data structure which is like a miniature map.  In the accessors for the `Map` indexer, check whether the chunk that contains the coordinate is loaded and if not load it.  Then delegate the `Map` indexer to the `Chunk` indexer.  The `Map` can keep track of which chunks are loaded using a `Dictionary`.  Finally, you need to unload chunks based on a strategy, e.g. least recently used.

With this infrastructure in place you can then use the `Map` as a virtual infinite plane.

Here's some (untested) pseudo-code to get you started:

```
public struct Coordinate : IEquatable<Coordinate>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Coordinate other)
    {
        return X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return X ^ Y;
    }
}

public class Data
{
    // Map data goes here.
}

public class Chunk
{
    public Coordinate Origin { get; set; }
    public Data[,] Data { get; set; }

    public Data this[Coordinate coord]
    {
        get { return Data[coord.X - Origin.X, coord.Y - Origin.Y]; }
        set { Data[coord.X - Origin.X, coord.Y - Origin.Y] = value; }
    }
}

public class Map
{
    private Dictionary<Coordinate, Chunk> map = new Dictionary<Coordinate,Chunk>();

    public Data this[Coordinate coord]
    {
        get
        {
            Chunk chunk = LoadChunk(coord);
            return chunk[coord];
        }
        set
        {
            Chunk chunk = LoadChunk(coord);
            chunk[coord] = value;
        }
    }

    private Chunk LoadChunk(Coordinate coord)
    {
        Coordinate origin = GetChunkOrigin(coord);
        if (map.ContainsKey(origin))
        {
            return map[origin];
        }
        CheckUnloadChunks();
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk { Origin = origin, Data = new Data[16, 16] };
        map.Add(origin, chunk);
        return chunk;
    }

    private void CheckUnloadChunks()
    {
        // Unload old chunks.
    }

    private Coordinate GetChunkOrigin(Coordinate coord)
    {
        return new Coordinate { X = coord.X / 16 * 16, Y = coord.Y / 16 * 16 };
    }
}
```